Error in the Angular Material Documentation: Email Checker
If I specify aa@aa as email, then it doesn't show up as an error. So is Angular’s ​​email checker wrong?
https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples#input-error-state-matcher


Perfectly valid address for a local domain with no TLD.

you can see the regExpr in github: const EMAIL_REGEXP =     /^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\=?^_{|}~-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_{|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
